# How to perform a left join using OR for multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, database, left-join

My question is very basic as it deals with two tables: reservations and events.

Table reservations contains 5 column which indicate the event type, this is a number.

For example:

```
table reservations

event_1  event_2  event_3  event_4  event_5
181      177      485      772      474
```

Table events contain the details about the event.

For example:

```
table events

id     event_key    location
181    8888512      10
177    2255998      88
485    7895201      12
772    1212855      22
474    2125495      10
```

I would like to be able to write a query to which I will provide an event_key, and using the id from the table events, get to the reservations table.

I have a limited knowledge of using joins, or sub-queries, I can get the idea with some explanation and help but I am unsure as to what method will get me the results I need. I hope that through this question I can get a bit of good help.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

This is the type of query I was thinking of:

```
SELECT 
    e.[id],
    e.[event_key],
    e.[event_location],
    e.[event_room],
    e.[event_description],
    e.[event_instructor], 
    r.[reservation_id], 
    r.[guest_first_name], 
    r.[guest_last_name], 
    r.[guest_age], 
    r.[guest_city], 
    et-cetera...
FROM events e 
LEFT JOIN reservations r
ON e.id IN (r.event_1, r.event_2, r.event_3, r.event_4, r.event_5)
WHERE e.event_key IN ('8888512', '7895201', '2125495')
```

Comment: What would the output look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine if event is `event_1`, `event_2` and so on, you need to `UNPIVOT` the `reservation` table and `JOIN` it with the `event` table:

```
DECLARE @event_key INT = 2125495;

WITH CteUnpivotReservations(event_id, event_type) AS(
    SELECT event_1, 'event_1' FROM reservations UNION ALL
    SELECT event_2, 'event_2' FROM reservations UNION ALL
    SELECT event_3, 'event_3' FROM reservations UNION ALL
    SELECT event_4, 'event_4' FROM reservations UNION ALL
    SELECT event_5, 'event_5' FROM reservations
)
SELECT
    r.*
FROM CteUnpivotReservations r
INNER JOIN event e
    ON r.event_id = e.id
WHERE
    e.event_key = @event_key
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/629fa/2/0)

Comment: Hello Felix, thank you for your sharing your solution. I forgot to include a bit more details and I apologize for that. The query will be running from an Access database against linked tables in SQL Server. I don't think using the WITH clause is available in Access. I was thinking the query should look something like what I am posting under UPDATE, please let me know what you think. Thanks.